# Как сделать загрузку как с социальных сетей?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Привет Всем! Вот хотел спросить как осуществлять показ загрузки как, например,. с фейсбук и контакта.
**1.** Например, я сделал 2 блока, которые обновляется через ajax. Но проблема в том, что они появляются только тогда, когда весь сайт уже загрузился. А до этого пустое место с названием блока.
**2.** У меня есть файл обработки cmd.php. У меня много кнопок настроек пользователя идут через этот файл. Хотел спросить, можно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку оно не переходило на файл, а ыыполняла на той же страничке.( Если 2 вопрос не ясен, могу уточнить.
П.с не минусуйте меня =)

**Добавлено.**

Вот код

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
 function show() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "blocks/maintrackertoolbar_block.php",
         cache: false,
         success: function (html) {
             $("#content").html(html);
         }
     });
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     show();
     setInterval('show()', 10000);
 });
</script>
```

Увидел действительно `$(document).ready();` но без него не работает =)

Comment: Ребята у кого есть скайп? Чтобы помогли мне, не хочу здесь флудить своей глупостью.

Comment: Если интересно как делает Вконтакте, то они реализовали это в node.js. Почитайте, мощная штука.

Comment: На мою честь назвали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поставьте изначально в блоке - изображение загрузки! После того, как полностью сайт загрузится и получил контент от других страниц, он заменит изображение на контент.
2. Отправляйте запросы через ajax на файл cmd.php, получайте ответ - выводите.

**Добавлено.**

```
    function show() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "blocks/maintrackertoolbar_block.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#content").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        show();
        setInterval('show()', 10000);
    });
```

Вот так попробуйте.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ - методом post
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ - методом get

почитайте, поищите примеры и поймёте, как отправлять, чтобы оставалось всё на той же странице.

Comment: Немогли вы мне написать пример, если Вам не тяжело. Я на этих языках ноль. Думаю что там как-то через цикл if, а что проверять я не знаю =)

Comment: http://scarj.asia/stati/programmirovanie/236-otpravka-dannyx-na-server-s-pomoshhyu-jquery.html

как пример, я думаю вам подойдёт.

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: skype: heyhey---cocacola

Answer (score 2):

1. Выполняйте первоначальную инициализацию напрямую, т.е. не оборачивая в $(document).ready();
2. Ничего не понял, но интуиция подскаызвает, что если кнопочка обрабатывается по $.click() на jQuery, то не хватает return false; в конце. Но это только интуиция, вы бы уточнили...

**Добавлено.**

Почитайте [вот это](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-ajax/). Если на вскидку, то вам нужно просто добавить к Вашему исходному коду show(); и все. Т.е. получается

```
<script>
    function show(){...}//Объявили
    show();//Первый вызов(инициализация начального контента)
    $(document).ready(...);//Подгрузка в процессе жизни страницы
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Я вас чуть не понял, я 0 в jquery, ajax
2. Кнопки у меня как ссылка например <a href = 'cmd.php?session=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&amp;command=block_top_torrent_on,15'> кнопка </a> как сделать чайнику(т.е мне)  чтобы не переходила на страничку cmd.php, а как в ВКОНТАКТЕ показывала ниже кнопки загрузку и обрабатывалось на страничке без переходов

Comment: 1. Везде учат все функции на jquery оборачивать в $(document).ready(); т.е. что бы они выполнялись когда уже сформирована DOM элемента. Вам нужно первоначальную подгрузку делать без этой обертки. Вообще было бы неплохо увидеть код! Заочно ставят диагноз только прорицатели и иже с ними.  
2. Вам уже посоветовал товарищ @V_Tjuryakin использовать ajax. Если у Вас с ним ну совсем туго - могу показать примерный шаблон.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: Почитайте [вот это][1]. Если на вскидку, то вам нужно просто добавить к Вашему исходному коду show(); и все. Т.е. получается  

    <script>
        function show(){...}//Объявили
        show();//Первый вызов(инициализация начального контента)
        $(document).ready(...);//Подгрузка в процессе жизни страницы
    </script>


  [1]: http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-ajax/